# Django channels websocket reconnect

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels, reconnect

I am building a messaging system in Django, using web-socket to receive the message.

Here is my tryouts,

```
from channels.consumer import AsyncConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

class ChatConsumer(AsyncConsumer):

    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print("connected", event)
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept"
        })

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        print("receive", event)
        message = event['text']
        obj = await self.create_obj(message=message)
        print('Created...')

    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print("disconnected", event)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def create_obj(self, **kwargs):
        obj = ChatMessage.objects.create(message=kwargs['message'])
        return obj
```

When I start a client app the web-socket is connected, and i can receive the message and i am able to store into the DB.

```
connected {'type': 'websocket.connect'}
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/message [192.168.0.101:50148]
```

After some idle time, the web-socket disconnects automatically,

```
Application instance <Task pending coro=<SessionMiddlewareInstance.__call__() running at /Users/ajay/Desktop/workspace/projects/python/django/websock/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/sessions.py:183> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x10b311510>()]>> for connection <WebSocketProtocol client=['192.168.0.101', 50148] path=b'/ws/message'> took too long to shut down and was killed.
```

After disconnects, i am not able to receive the message, when i reload the client, web-socket is connected, is there any way to reconnect the we-socket automatically with out reloading the client. I request to guide me some suggestion to achieve this, it will be very helpful for me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but this answer may help others. You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/reconnecting-websocket

Comment: Please don't just recommend a library without any information about what the library is or how, specifically, it can be used to solve this specific problem. [Learn more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251602/recommending-off-site-resources-when-questions-dont-ask-for-it/251605#251605).

Answer (score 0):

it seems your client kill the connection.I face the same problem when use as client import websockets".

```
 # part of Client Code in the main while loop
 while not self.finished:
        try:
            self.websocket = await websockets.client.connect(
                self.connect_url,
                max_size=None,
                extra_headers=self.extra_headers
            )
.....
# in your`s producer
.......
 while True:
        # Make sure connection is still live.
        pong_waiter = await self.websocket.ping()
        await pong_waiter # if you will not await in 10-20 sec connection will close.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i am sorry to say that, i'm not able to understand this, actually my client was Flutter(Android App), can you please guide me based on my tryouts. Thanks in advance