# Django channels get the current channel

Tags: django, django-channels

I want to save messages to my database, but I want to devide them by channels, currently I load messages from other channels from the database, I am wondering how can I get something unique about a certain channel so I could have a field in my model named channel for that?

Edit: To possibly elaborste my question, is there a way I can acces the room instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable channel_layers then every time a consumer instance (channel) is created it will automatically instantiate a channel name. This can be accessed from within the consumer with self.channel_name.

**Edit:** The channel_name is completely unique to the channel meaning every client that connects will have a unique channel name associated with it.

Comment: Correct. For example in my project when a user opens a connection with my web app a channel is opened and I pass the unique channel name that is created to a long-running background task that then uses the channel name to send data back to the user who first called the long-running task.

Comment: Ok, so I guess if I were to have mutilple channels, I should save the channel_name in the message object, thanks

Comment: Yes that would be one way to do it if your aim is to define where each message comes from using the channel_name.

Comment: Hmm but each time I refresh the page the current channels name also changes, and so I dont get my messages from my database.

Comment: But using room name fixes that issue, as that is oermament, is it ok to stick with that?

Comment: Yes you can use group names as well it just depends on your situation. Also note that the refreshing page issue can be fixed using Django Sessions.

Comment: But I think even with a session if I were to restart the server and possibly re-login it would be gone wouldnt it?

Comment: You would have to store the session info or other unique identifiers in a database. So say the user registers on your site then you generate a unique identifier for that user which will link any data you store about that user. When the user enters a chatroom (or whatever your web app is) you add his channel to the group but you also store the session info into a database. When the user refreshes you check the session info of that user to see what group the user was already in and put the new channel back in that same group. This means everytime a user opens a connection you check the database.

Comment: Here is also something that might help - instead of killing the connection when a user closes or refreshes the window, ping for a certain amount of time. This means that if the user refreshes than the client will ping back within a few seconds and the connection won't be closed and reopened. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61037587/django-channels-websocket-reconnect

Comment: Hmm ok, will keep that in mind about the second part, I am not sure how to understand the first comment though, currently I have it where the user is a object in the database and I assign a ForeignKey to the user when they send a message and save room name of where they sent the message in and when I open a room, it loads the messages that have the room name set to that and loads the messages combined with usernames of the users.


Btw, what would be the benefit of not closing the connection and pinging?

Comment: Pinging would just help avoid issues with a new channel being created every time someone refreshes the page. If you ping for a few seconds you can keep the same connection alive and avoid having to pull from your database again thereby reducing the load on the database. The way you have it set up is fine so you can ignore my first comment but what is the issue now? Your program is loading the room messages + users so did you reach what you wanted?

Comment: I guess I have, my problem was with the channel names that you did a great job explaining to me about and I learned some more about the way that channels work from you, thank you.